# Errors in Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, command-line

I know that the problem lies in the command line, but I have tried every which way to find a way to solve it, but I have completely no idea how I can fix the array to not be zero. I am still really new to arrays and have looked everywhere in my textbook on how to do this, but  the only example does not include arrays.

here is the error I am getting.

I am using Netbean

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at arraysize.Arraysize.main(Arraysize.java:20)
```

Here is my code as well

```
package arraysize;



public class Arraysize {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[ 10 ];
    for ( int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++)
    array[counter] = Integer.parseInt(args[counter]);
   System.out.printf("%s%8s\n", "Index", "Value");

    for (int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++)
       System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", counter, array[counter]);


}

}
```

Comment: This is no {} after for loop?

Comment: what is the input your passing from command line ?

Comment: I'm going to assume it's because you're not passing any command line arguments.

Comment: Please don't ask the exact same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your input `args` array length is less than length of `array`, in the moment you iterate to **10** in row 
 `array[counter] = Integer.parseInt(args[counter]);`
and in moment `counter` variable exceed `args` length you get exception, for solve this you need to
pass `args` array with 10 or more length. To check`args` array argument you may pass it's size to console:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.printf("arguments array size is: %d", args.length); 
         //your code
}
```